# C++ Bool values not working

Tags: c++, windows, boolean

So I am making a basic tic-tac-toe program for a school project, and I am trying to work with bool values to end the game when a combination is activated. I am currently using a C++ WinForm to display the game. I have a MyForm.cpp and a MyForm.h that run the code.

The code is in the MyForm.h file, the only thing I have in MyForm.cpp is the command to run the Form.

In case you need the MyForm.cpp code:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Tic_Tac_Toe::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Beginning of the MyForm.h code

Here are my bool values:

```
char player = 'X';
bool b1x = false;
bool b1o = false;
```

Here is the code that triggers the bool when a button is clicked:

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (player == 'X' && b1o == false) {
        button1->BackgroundImage = Image::FromFile("File_Location");
        b1x = true;
        player = 'O';
    }
    else if (player == 'O' && b1x == false) {
         button1->BackgroundImage = Image::FromFile("File_Location");
         b1o = true;
         player = 'X';
    }
}
```

Here is the code that displays a message when the combination is hit

```
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); \
            if (b1x == true && b2x == true && b3x == true) {
                MessageBox::Show("X Wins!");
            }
    }
```

I have tried to do everything possible to figure out the code, and I have tried to tie the bools together in every way, but when I do a combination across (for example; Tile 1, Tile 2, and Tile 3), it just keeps going. It doesn't display the message, and I am still able to click the tiles (I will be linking a way to restart the game once the combination is hit)

Other Failed Attempts:

```
public:
MyForm(void)
{
    InitializeComponent(); \
        if (b1x && b2x && b3x) {
            MessageBox::Show("X Wins!");
        }
}
//////////////////////////////////////
public:
MyForm(void)
{
    InitializeComponent(); \
        if (b1x && b2x && b3x) {
            system("PAUSE");
        }
}
```

I know for certain that something is wrong with the bool values, because when I click the tile, it changes the image and then sets the bool to true (based on the tile number and the player it is on (x or o). It just doesn't recognize when all three bool values are true. Please help, I have tried for days to figure this out, and I have scoured the web using every resource available.

[**EDIT**] I have tried running through my code hundreds of times over the past week, and I have tried every solution that was given to me from every website imaginable. I have changed the settings on my debugger to show me the warnings in my program, and it hasn't given me any. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong in the code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have stepped through each line of code involving the bool values and the buttons I am using (which is about 423 lines of code). I have looked through each line and tried to use a different solution in hopes of finding an answer. I have my debugger settings set to the settings suggested by the link you provided, and it has given me no warnings. I have no solution to use after looking online and editing my code to try and fix my problem.

Comment: _" have stepped through each line of code involving the bool values and the buttons I am using "_ Did you watch how the values are changing also?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I just went through my code and identified that the bool values returned true using MessageBox::Show() within an if statement.

Comment: You are missing some combinations in your `if` statements.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If I am missing combinations in my if statements, can you at least point them out?

Comment: Example, the `b1o` can be **`true`** or false.  Likewise with `b1x`.  You are not checking those conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your tests for a win are only written into the Constructor of MyForm.

The Constructor ONLY runs at the very beginning, when the object is first created!
I assume no player has made any moves yet, so no one has won.

You need to re-run the test for a Win after a player makes a move.

Comment: Could you explain where I should locate my if statements? I tried moving them around, but I don't know exactly where I should put them. Or if you know how I would rerun the tests after a move, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "You need to re-run the test after a player makes a move".  Which function is called when a player makes a move?  I think it is `button1_Click`

Comment: I went through my code and added a bool value for the re-run called retest. Whenever the button is clicked, it will trigger the entire code of the combination if statements, let's hope this works... [**Edit**] I just attempted the retest statement and it didn't work, can you provide me with some code to use?